# Refresh only a div on click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

After i click the button i want to refresh only  `<div class="wrap"> ... </div>`
With this  `window.location.reload()` but  i refresh whole page, so i need a ajax script that will refresh only that div.

```
<div class="wrap">

    // Content

    <div class="random_dil">
    <a class="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" href="#">Sljedeće pitanje</a>
    </div>
```

I tried this

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<a id="refresh">click</a>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#mydiv").load("http://blah.com/page.php")
  })
})
</script>
```

But this again refresh whole site.

Comment: `$("#mydiv").load("http://blah.com/page.php")` should put content in DIV, not reloading all site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick reload the div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413200/onclick-reload-the-div-only)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://blah.com/page.php",
    async: true
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#mydiv").html(result);
});
```

Comment: Why would this work while `$("#mydiv").load("http://blah.com/page.php")` wasn't working?

Comment: @A. Wolff If you use iframe instead of div, i think the load("url") will work fine without reloading entire page.

Comment: `load()` ajax method works for any type of element which accepts any content, as DIV   https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @A. Wolff: I'm not having clear idea about load(), so i always keep on this way $(id).html(content);

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that the entire page is being recreated inside the mydiv area, IE click is added into my div when you click it. It is because that is what page.php is providing, jquery can select only a portion of the page to do that change the third line of your scrip to.

```
$("#mydiv").load("http://blah.com/page.php #mydiv" );
```

In your 2nd "also tried" example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  return null;
}

function ajax_function(url, postData, id)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                            
    }       
}                
    xmlhttp.send(postData);
 }

 function refreshDiv()
 {
var params = '';
var DivId  = 'wrap';
    var url    = 'http://blah.com/page.php';

ajax_function(url, params, DivId);
 }
 </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

// Content

<div class="random_dil">
<a class="button" onclick="refreshDiv()" href="#">Sljedeće pitanje</a>
</div>
```